get_option('siteurl') returns the website URL with HTTP prefix but not with HTTS prefix
I have the following source code in my WP theme:
<form action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform">

That outputs the website URL with HTTP prefix:

While my website works with HTTPS (Nginx redirects all HTTP requests to HTTPS).
And the comments are not added due to a security error in a browser.
How to update this source code to output the website URL with HTTPS prefix?
My wp-config.php does not contain SITEURL.

Update the actual site URL in your WP settings - you apparently still have http://... set in there.

@CBroe Where are they? I tried grep -i http wp-config.php, but did not find them.

@CBroe oh yes, they are on the Settings page in the admin panel! https://slogpost.ru/wp-admin/options-general.php Now the comments work!
